# Node.js won't open. "FOLDERNAME is a directory"?

Tags: node.js, terminal

I'm on the very first page of the w3schools tutorial for using Node.js, and I'm already stuck. So I'm assuming I've done something very stupid, but nevertheless here I am. I've downloaded Node.js, and it downloaded successfully according to my Terminal. But when I try to open my file via terminal:

```
/Users/MYNAME/Desktop/FOLDERNAME>node server.js
```

It simply says:

```
-bash: /Users/MYNAME/Desktop/FOLDERNAME: is a directory
```

And doesn't do anything else, and when I try to access the server I was supposed to have created, it doesn't work.

Any ideas?
Sorry for such a boring beginner question. I'm sorry it had to come to this. I'm on a Mac if that helps.

Comment: You can't type in a command inside of a file path. you need to instead input `node /Users/MYNAME/Desktop/FOLDERNAME/server.js`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't type in a command inside of a file path. you need to instead input `node /Users/MYNAME/Desktop/FOLDERNAME/server.js`.

A bit more: 
`node` is the program/command line utility that you are using and it takes a file path as an argument and does whatever logic (in this case it'll compile and run the JavaScript code in your server.js file).

Comment: Wow thank you so much for taking time out of your day to answer my question! It works now!